# how to get data from mysql in php page in proper way?

Tags: php, mysql

My Mysql table contains one column Let's discuss together!! when when i get it into php page ? is displaying in place of ' means Let�s discuss together!!   . So how to to get data from mysql in php page in proper way

Comment: `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">`

Comment: or you can simply convert that variable also through `utf8_decode` method like, `utf8_decode($variable)`

Answer (score 0):

You required to use `charset=UTF-8`in your page. Add this line in you page,

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
```

Comment: can u answer of  my question in the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47209500/export-issue-by-php-through-mysql-in-excel-file/47209618?noredirect=1#comment81391464_47209618